# Use of $this->alias

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Can someone tell me what does `$this->alias` do or mean in cakephp?

Answer (score 4):

`$this->alias` is the name of your model. For instance, if you have a model named User, `$this->alias` will be equal to `'User'`.

Answer (score 0):

Further to the other answer, Cake models have the property $this->name, which is the name of the model.  $this->alias is normally the same value, but in some contexts it is different, for example:

```
class MyModel extends AppModel {

    $hasOne = [
        'OtherModelAlias' => [
            'className' => 'OtherModel'
        ]
    ];
}
```

When dealing with this associated model OtherModel from the class MyModel, you would refer to it by $this->OtherModelAlias.  The value of `$this->OtherModelAlias->alias` is 'OtherModelAlias', but `$this->OtherModelAlias->name` is 'OtherModel'

Answer (score 0):

We use $this->alias when we write some code within the model itself. For example, if we are trying to access a data after form submit,

Model: User.php

$this->data[$this->alias]["email"]   --------------(1)

---

Controller: UsersController.php

$this->request->data["Users"]["email"] ----------------(2)

---

Both (1) and (2) implies the same email field submitted in the form.

N.B: $this->data[$this->alias]["email"] is same as $this->data["User"]["email"], but it's better if we follow the former and stick to the CakePHP conventions. Better safe than sorry! :)

Peace! xD